# error in calculating gradient use python

Tags: python-2.7, gradient

I use the following formule to calculate the gradient

```
gradient = [f(x+h) - f(x-h)] / 2h
```

and I test it with a linear function, but something is wrong.
The code is here:

```
import numpy as np

def evla_numerical_gradient(f, x):

    gradient = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    delta_x = 0.00001

    it = np.nditer(x, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])

    while not it.finished:
        index = it.multi_index
        x_old = x[index]

        x[index] = x_old + delta_x
        fx_addh = f(x)
        print(fx_addh)

        x[index] = x_old - delta_x
        fx_minush = f(x)
        print(fx_minush)

        x[index] = x_old

        print((fx_addh - fx_minush) / (2 * delta_x))
        gradient[index] = (fx_addh - fx_minush) / (2. * delta_x)

        it.iternext()

    return gradient


def lin(x):
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([0.001])
    grad = evla_numerical_gradient(lin, x)
    print(grad)
```

The result is here:

```
[ 0.00101]
[ 0.00099]
[ 0.]
[ 0.]
```

Why the gradient at x is 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is on the following combination of lines (I show the example of `fx_addh`, the case of `fx_minush` is similar

```
fx_addh = f(x)
x[index] = x_old
```

You are placing the result of `f(x)` into `fx_addh`. But the problem is that the way you have defined `f(x)`, which is just a handle to your `lin(x)` you are returning the argument directly.

In Python assignment operations do not copy objects, but create a binding between a target (on the left of the assignment `=`) and the object (on the right of the assignment `=`). More on this [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html).

To convince yourself that this is happening you can place another `print(fx_addh)` after the line in which you set `x[index] = x_old`; and you will see that it now contains the value zero.

To fix this you can modify your `lin(x)` function to return a copy of the object passed in as an argument:

```
import numpy as np
import copy

def evla_numerical_gradient(f, x):

    gradient = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=np.float64)
    delta_x = 0.00001

    it = np.nditer(x, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])

    while not it.finished:
        index = it.multi_index
        x_old = x[index]

        x[index] = x_old + delta_x
        fx_addh = f(x)
        print(fx_addh)

        x[index] = x_old - delta_x
        fx_minush = f(x)
        print(fx_minush)

        x[index] = x_old

        print((fx_addh - fx_minush) / (2 * delta_x))
        gradient[index] = (fx_addh - fx_minush) / (2. * delta_x)

        it.iternext()

    return gradient


def lin(x):
    return copy.copy(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = np.array([0.001])
    grad = evla_numerical_gradient(lin, x)
    print(grad)
```

Which returns:

```
[ 0.00101]
[ 0.00099]
[ 1.]
[ 1.]
```

Indicating a gradient of `1` as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

Because `fx_addh` and `fx_minush` are pointing to the same index of the memory. change the `lin` function to this:

```
def lin(x):
    return x.copy()
```

result:

```
[ 0.00101]
[ 0.00099]
[ 1.]
[ 1.]
```